# Custom Search - Agreement Terms

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I need clarification on the Custom Search for Azure.

When you go to the Custom Search site (http://customsearch.ai) and click sign up, it takes you to an agreement page. The second paragraph says if you don’t have an Azure subscription, you can’t use it on commercial websites. If you buy a subscription, would you be able to use it on a commercial site? Could you use it on a commercial site during the free trial period with the intention to pay for the service, if it did what I wanted to?

Answer (score 0):

All APIs on Cognitive Services are meant for commercial use. So, with the free trial keys (and with the paid keys as well), if the APIs suits your requirements, you can use them for your service. Make sure you oblige to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/use-and-display-requirements.